# Docker compose unexpectedly replaces environment: VAR=* with an ls of the contents of the root folder inside the container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose service defined with an environment variable:

```
    command: /run.sh
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    environment:
      - TEST=*
```

In `run.sh` I have the following echo statement:

```
echo TEST: ${TEST}
```

The unexpected result of that echo statement is an ls of the root folder inside the docker container.

```
TEST: bin dev etc home lib media mnt opt proc root run run.sh sbin secrets srv static sys tmp usr var
```

My goal is to set the environment variable to the literal value `*`.

I've tried single quoting it and escaping it:

```
    environment:
      - TEST='*'

    environment:
      - TEST=\*
```

In those two cases I get the literal values `'*'` and `\*` passed in, both of which break the app that I'm using because it's expecting the value to be a single `*` character, not quoted or escaped.

GPT4 considered this unexpected behavior and I'm not finding much on it in google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is unrelated to docker-compose.

Unquoted variable expansion *in the shell* undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. `*` is filename expansion trigger *in shell*. `*` is replaced by the list of files in the current working directory in the shell script you are running with `/bin/sh`.

Quote variable expansion to prevent filename expansion and word splitting expansion. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

```
echo TEST: "$TEST"
```

Comment: That's infuriatingly obvious in hindsight, thank you very much for catching that.